# Find line breaks

Tags: jquery

I`m using a javascript to find ideal font size for any size of screen that can fill a div with special width of it self (like 70% or 40% of parent )  and i want to achieve this goal by making a 0.1em font size text bigger by 0.1em until it fill the parent width or if any line break happen . i tried to find how bigger my text height get after using new font size and if new height is bigger than 1.7 * last height i stop the script because there should be line break there but this code is not working on some smaller devices . is there any way to find line breaks using  jquery that works on all screen sizes ?

here is my code :

```
var fit = function(inner , outter)
{
    var $inner = $("#"+inner), //rememver "var"
    $outter = $("#"+outter),
    fsize = 0.1 ;
    while(true)
    {
        var fheight = $outter.height();
        var a = fsize + "em" ;
        $inner.css({'font-size' : a});
        if((1.7 * fheight) < $outter.height() )
        {
            fsize = fsize - 0.1 ;
            a = fsize + "em";
            $inner.css({'font-size' : a});
            return; //change breck with return (that return all function)
        }
        if($outter.width() < $inner.width())
        {
            fsize = fsize - 0.1 ;
            a = fsize + "em";
            $inner.css({'font-size' : a});
            return; //change breck with return (that return all function)
        }
        fsize = fsize + 0.1 ;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Can it be done using px values of font-size, instead em's ?

Check this solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/68LCb/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="asd">asdasd asd Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.asd {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    /*unfortunatelly THIS has to be specified; */
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    shrinkText($('.asd'));
})

function shrinkText(d) {
    d.css({'font-size': parseInt(d.css('font-size'))+1});
    var diff = d.height() - parseInt(d.css('line-height'));
    console.log(diff);
    if (diff > 0 )
        d.css({'font-size': parseInt(d.css('font-size'))-1});
    else
        shrinkText(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/AyUgUhO/2/edit?html,js,output

Using this lil piece of code

```
 var p = $('p'), w = $(document.body).innerWidth();
 p.css({
   'font-size': '1px',
   'float': 'left',
   'white-space': 'nowrap'
 });
 for(var i = 1; i < w; ++i){
   p.css({
     'font-size': i+'px'
   });
   if(p.width() > w) return;
 }
```